# Get data from API and save it to txt with Python

Tags: python, api, get

I need to get data from this API https://api.storj.io/contacts/f52624d8ef76df81c40853c22f93735581071434 (sample node)

This is my code (python):

```
import requests
f = requests.get('https://api.storj.io/contacts/f52624d8ef76df81c40853c22f93735581071434')
print f.text
```

I want to save only protocol, responseTime and reputation in three subsequent lines of the txt file. It's supposed to look something like this::

```
protocol: 1.2.0
responseTime: 8157.912472694088
reputation: 1377
```

Unfortunately, I'm stuck at this point and I can not process this data in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
f = requests.get('https://api.storj.io/contacts/f52624d8ef76df81c40853c22f93735581071434')

# Store content as json
answer = f.json()

# List of element you want to keep
items = ['protocol', 'responseTime', 'reputation']

# Display
for item in items:
    print(item + ':' + str(answer[item]))

# If you want to save in a file
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for item in items:
        print(item + ':' + str(answer[item]), file=text_file)
```

Hope it helps! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unrefined way to do what you want that you could build off of.  You'd need to sub in a path/filename for text.txt.

```
import requests
import json

f = requests.get('https://api.storj.io/contacts/f52624d8ef76df81c40853c22f93735581071434')
t = json.loads(f.text)

with open('text.txt', 'a') as mfile:
  mfile.write("protocol: {0}".format(str(t['protocol'])))
  mfile.write("responseTime: {0}".format(str(t['responseTime'])))
  mfile.write("reputation: {0}".format(str(t['reputation'])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to transform to a JSON object to be able to access the keys

```
import requests
import simplejson as json

f = requests.get('https://api.storj.io/contacts/f52624d8ef76df81c40853c22f93735581071434')

x = json.loads(f.text)

print 'protocol: {}'.format(x.get('protocol'))
print 'responseTime: {}'.format(x.get('responseTime'))
print 'reputation: {}'.format(x.get('reputation'))
```